# Can I use Next.js frontend app as Block in Shopify's Theme App Extensions instead of liquid?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shopify, shopify-app, storyblok

I have a **frontend** developed using **Next.js** in which I **consumed Storyblok API** to get dynamic content.

I want to use it as a **Block** in **Theme App Extension** instead of refactoring the code into liquid

Is that possible?

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Ps:

- If there is a better way to do that let me know
- I tried adding it as IFrame but it is not recommended for SEO and performance

Answer (score 0):

Go for it. You can do whatever you want in a block. You control the HTML(Liquid), JS, and CSS.

Note that you are probably killing a fly with a sledgehammer but that is your burden to bear. If your block is somehow slow or in-efficient, it'll show, but maybe it'll be zippy and great. Just throw down the code and see what happens. Should not take you more than a few minutes to establish whether you like it or not.